# div transition on click before page load CSS

Tags: css, transition

On this page I am making I have a button at the bottom of the page, which has to get wider and then move up when clicked. After the button has reached its new place, new content should load.
I have found a lot about CSS transitions an animations on hover, but I want to use this as a page transition. 
How do I get this transition to happen before loading the new page??
I would love to do this with as little JS as possible..
Thanx Y'all!

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: Would be great to understand what you want a little better... if you just want the button to animate before the link is followed, you can use fire a function on click of the button that has a setTimeout wrap around a redirect i.e. `window.location.href = "url";`. But is that what you want? Sounds like you want something more like an AJAX response.

Comment: you can detect the end of css transitions, using the `transitionend / webkitTransitionEnd / oTransitionEnd` event, but you'll need at least some javascript to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you asked:

This delays the page load until the transition is complete (the setTimeout just need to be set to whatever the duration of the CSS transition is).

```
$('.link').click(function () {
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
  setTimeout( function() {
    window.location.href = "url for page goes here";
  }, 500);//set 500 to whatever timeout you want
});
```

See pen example: (http://cdpn.io/vyuch)

**BUT**

This is not a good idea... If CSS transitions aren't available, it will just look like a terrible link and confuse users. If they are, it is still slow and frustrating.

If you want the content to load on the same page, you need to use AJAX. To help with this, some more information would be helpful...